# How to find out the particular column number of a matrix where the value '1' is present in r?

Tags: r

I have matrix of four column with one observation as given below

0  1  0  0

Now I want to find out the column number where the value '1' is present, say for example for the above given row the value '1' is in 2 column. How can I do that in r? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `which(your_matrix == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)` gives the positions (rows and columns) of all 1s.

Comment: Thanks. I want only the particular number of that column where the value '1' is present.

Comment: If `m` is a one-row matrix of 0's and one 1 then this finds the position of the one: `max.col(m)`

Comment: Thanks G.Grothendieck. It works fine!

Comment: If there is only one row, then just do `which(as.logical(m1))`

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments, here's what you need -

```
unique(which(your_matrix == 1, arr.ind = T)[,"col"])
```

If only one row then -

```
which(your_matrix == 1)
```